# git (plumbing) has a file changed between two commits?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-plumbing

Is there a git (preferably plumbing) command to check if a file has changed between two commits?

I can check this with a little grep but this does not feel like the cleanest solution:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~4 -- filename | grep -q filename
```

**EDIT** : I want the return code to reflect whether the file has changed or not.

Comment: `git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~4 -- filename` either report changes in the `filename` or doesn't. Why do you need `grep`?

Comment: I want the return code to reflect whether there are changes or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) says that you can use --exit-code option

> --exit-code
>   Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is, it exits
>   with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences.

```
git diff --exit-code HEAD HEAD~4 -- filename
```